# Cassandra fastest way to insert

Tags: python, performance, cassandra, insert, cassandra-3.0

I have been working on Cassandra for days to find what is the fastest and efficient way to insert data into Cassandra. Some people don't recommend using batch : https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/

I have tried batching and it was pretty fast, about 25k insert/s, but I found some issues like :

`Error : Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements cassandra`

Also, I found that it there was missing data... don't really know why.

I also tried with prepare statement and execute_async as you can see below:

```
query = "INSERT INTO leaks (value0, value1, value2, value3, value4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
prepared = session.prepare(query)

for row in data:
    try:
        session.execute_async(prepared, (cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(value0, value1, value2, value3, value4))
    except Exception as e:  
        print "An error occured : " + str(e)
        pass
```

With this code, I have about 3-4k insert/s. I'm wondering how much people get with inserting their data.

I have 3 nodes with each 6 cpu and 32gb of ram. I also set the commitlog to another disk.

Comment: What is the goal of this test? Try using a spark process to insert, it can easily push speeds over 100K inserts/sec.

Comment: Batch isn't a way for optimization of the inserts!

Comment: @dilsingi I don't know about Spark. Maybe I should take a look at it ! Alex, That's what I thought.

Answer (score 4):

Inserting data in batches isn't that bad. But you tried to insert more 65k records in a single batch which is above the batch limit. Remember cassandra has not a transaction in sense of relational databases.

Also it is a bad idea to have large batches and batches with many different partition keys. A single batch is handled by a single coordinator to take out the changes. If it happens that your batch contains a single partition key (not the entire primary key!) key you are lucky as the coordinator chosen could be a node holding that partition making this faster.

If your batch contains different partition keys that puts some more stress on the coordinator node to handle (and with luck all nodes are needed). When this happens on parallel batches your cluster will be busy.

It's in general faster to group your batches for matching partition keys and quite small batch sizes (I use 100 rows per batch), but you should experiment yourself finding your ideal batch size). Than use asynchronous queries for those batches (https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#asynchronous-queries). Doing so you will have many small batches running in parallel on all your nodes.

I can archive about 120k inserts per second on a 15 node cluster with about 8k payload per row, which is almost network link speed (~800MBit/s).

Comment: This is very interesting, I was trying batches with a 10 rows per batch. But it seems thats he was only inserting the half of the data and I don't know why. I will retry with batch and see why he is just inserting the half

Comment: If this is reproducible - have a look at your nodes: disk utilization, cpu utilization and errors in your logs. What's your hardware setup? What's the output of `nodetool tpstats`?